# Problem loading page - console.aws.amazon.com

Tags: 20.04, aws

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I am using Firefox 77.0.1 and can access almost all webpages. However, I can't access console.aws.amazon.com. I try on Firefox and Chrome. I am not using a proxy. I can access the URL aws.amazon.com, but not console.aws.amazon.com

I can access this page on windows 10 using Chrome, so the issue is not in my router.

On Ubuntu terminal, I receive the below message when I execute the command PING

```
PING us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com (54.239.31.91) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 54.239.31.91 (54.239.31.91): icmp_seq=1 ttl=214 time=223 ms
64 bytes from 54.239.31.91 (54.239.31.91): icmp_seq=2 ttl=214 time=144 ms
64 bytes from 54.239.31.91 (54.239.31.91): icmp_seq=3 ttl=214 time=165 ms
64 bytes from 54.239.31.91 (54.239.31.91): icmp_seq=4 ttl=214 time=188 ms
64 bytes from 54.239.31.91 (54.239.31.91): icmp_seq=5 ttl=214 time=211 ms
```

The error page:
**Secure Connection Failed
An error occurred during a connection to console.aws.amazon.com. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR
    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.**

Please, can you help?

Best regards,

Rosalvo Neto

Comment: A cache/cookie problem perhaps? Try `wget https://console.aws.amazon.com`. You should be redirected to `https://console.aws.amazon.com/console/home` and there download a file called `index.html`.

Comment: I have tried wget https://console.aws.amazon.com. However, I am not redirected to https://console.aws.amazon.com/console/home. I receive this message: Connecting to console.aws.amazon.com (console.aws.amazon.com)|54.239.31.91|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.

Comment: Try upgrading your certificates: `sudo apt upgrade ca-certificates`.

Comment: I receive this message after run sudo apt upgrade ca-certificates: ca-certificates is already the newest version (20190110ubuntu1.1).
ca-certificates set to manually installed.
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: "ca-certificates is set to manually installed"? Hmm. Try `sudo update-ca-certificates` then.

Comment: I run sudo update-ca-certificates. But after executing it, I still receive this message when I run wget https://console.aws.amazon.com:

Connecting to console.aws.amazon.com (console.aws.amazon.com)|54.239.31.91|:443... connected. Unable to establish SSL connection.

Additional Information:

I can connect my ec2 instance by ssh terminal. For example: ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@2001:db8:1234:1a00:9691:9503:25ad:1761

However, The sign-in page console.aws.amazon.com I can’t access… I need access this page to manage my account.

Comment: If `wget --no-check-certificate https://console.aws.amazon.com` also fails, it must be a network issue, e.g. a firewall blocking https traffic.

Comment: I guess the issue is not in the network, because I can access this page in my smartphone and another Windows 10 computer, both in the same wifi router. I think it is something about ca-certificates. However, I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Perhaps `sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh`. Perhaps reboot. Can you connect to e.g. `https://gmail.com` securely?

Comment: Yes, I can access https://gmail.com and other https sites without the problem.

I run sudo update-ca-certificates –fresh and reboot. But I have the same problem. In my ubuntu 16 LTS on this machine, I can access this page last week on the same wifi router. Only this week, when I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I can not access it.

Comment: [Another report of the same issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248816/https-connection-failure-when-trying-to-open-aws-console)

Comment: Same problem on mx linux. none of the solutions worked. Chromium and firefox are not working for aws and gives SSL error, but they are working fine for everything else. But google chrome is working fine for aws.